# Learner Question: How to use CSS to make buttons stay within container when window is reduced in size. SPFX Webparts

Tags: css, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm having trouble finding a solution for a minor problem with some prev/next buttons at the bottom of a webpart I've created. The buttons use Absolute and it's a relatively (pun?) easy way to get them where I want them on the page.

The reason why I use Absolute is because it prevents these buttons from jumping up and down, clinging to the very bottom of the last field of every page.

The problem with using Absolute is that if the web part is added to an SP web part section that is a different size, the buttons are misplaced.

I need something relative, but don't know where to put them in relation to my container. I've tried adding the buttons CSS into the container but that makes no difference.

I am using MS Fabric UI elements and I am using a container to hold certain aspects of the web part.
I need to know where to place and what CSS syntax to use for these two buttons.

Here's my CSS (it contains the container and the buttons, nextbutton and previousbutton).

```
.dataForm {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 1200px;
  } 

}

//End of dataForm (container?)
}

.nextButton {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;  
  left: 650px; //decrease to go left
  bottom: 25px; //decrease to go up
}

.previousButton {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;  
  left: 10px; 
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: set the container to position:relative then use percentage values instead of PX...

so the .nextButton will use right: % value

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Hi, I've finally fixed it. It was due to a lack of understanding of blocks. I simply segregated the two buttons using a block using a combination of css (creating a container for the buttons) and then, within the JSX render, I used that style with the <div> block (which was segregated from web parts container).